# Format CURREN_TIMESTAMP when output from database

Tags: sql-server, datetime, coldfusion

My QUESTION: I would like to update the format of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when reading it out of my database.

Background: I am using ColdFusion to INSERT the current time and date into a MSSQL database. But when I Select the time and date I would like to change the format before showing it in my HTML.

See my example below:

```
<cfquery name="insertSave" datasource="RC">
                INSERT INTO     Contact_Forms (Submission_Date,Data,Status,User_ID)
                VALUES          (
                                        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                        '#ARGUMENTS.formData#',
                                        '#ARGUMENTS.formStatus#',
                                        '#ARGUMENTS.usr_ID#'
                                )
            </cfquery>
```

Above CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is saved in this format: `2015-04-22 10:16:37.207`

How when I select that from the database can I change the format to: `04-22-2015 10:16`

Comment: Formatting dates should be left to the presentation tier - it seems you can do this with the [date + time formatting functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6de0.html)  `DateFormat(dateFromSql, "mm-dd-yyyy ") TimeFormat(dateFromSql, "HH:mm")`

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx is a useful list of date conversion options.

Comment: Why would you choose this specific output? Do you just want to make life harder for people when the output is September 7th or May 11th?

Comment: @StuartLC, you posted your prose in the wrong place.  It's more of an answer than a comment.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm no cold fusion expert - I stumbled across this via the Sql-Server tags and will gladly stand correction.

Comment: *Above CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is saved in this format* Technically, it is not saved in that format.  It is saved as a number. The human friendly format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.l is applied by whatever client you are using SSMS, etcetera to display the dates.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments this should be formatted in the presentation layer. If you're using ColdFusion 10 or higher you can use [`dateTimeFormat()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateTimeFormat)

```
#dateTimeFormat(Submission_Date, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:nn')#
```

If you're using ColdFusion 9 or lower you can do

```
#dateFormat(Submission_Date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')# #timeFormat(Submission_Date, 'hh:mm')#
```